# Working off a commit 5 commits ago. How does one do this best?

Tags: git

Say I have a `git log` that looks like this:

```
commit 8379fef8952c9fde4c4f8bb9b3fb5dab80a61bc9
...

commit cc6c393f707da82aa3f0753db81b148d7eddaaf1
...

commit 6668e9087e3561b7797c91730f4ac0057fa85904
...

commit 2da2d26974d1ef57a02f3dfe2c7b5aa310f2efac
...

commit a625c16a2985d06f10fb72db9e6952fdf51e5000
...
```

Say I want to revert back to the bottom one `a625c16...` and that all the work above it is terrible. I basically want to blow away everything I did in the last 4 commits and restart from the bottom commit. When I checkout that commit, I'm on `no branch` and a detached HEAD state. What does that mean? What needs to be done so I can continue working on this branch but from 4 commits ago?

Comment: Assuming you are working on branch `master` then rename it to e.g. `BAD_BRANCH`, then create a new `master` branch from your last good commit. If you decide you do need any of the changes in `BAD_BRANCH` then you can merge those to your new `master` branch later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you haven't pushed this, you can do

```
git reset --hard a625c16a2985d06f10fb72db9e6952fdf51e5000
```

This will discard all the changes completely and forget they every happened. However, this will mean that you will have to do `git push --force` if you've published this anywhere, which might be considered dangerous / antisocial.

If you want to avoid that you can do

```
git revert 8379fef8952c9fde4c4f8bb9b3fb5dab80a61bc9
...
git revert 2da2d26974d1ef57a02f3dfe2c7b5aa310f2efac
```

Which will cleanly backout all the changes, and you'll be able to push without --force. This does mean all your changes and reversions will be visible in the history.

Comment: what if I have pushed it?

Comment: as I said in the answer, do the reverts, or use --force

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the commit you want checked out as detached HEAD, you can simply do `git branch -f branchname && git checkout branchname`.